Integral of stochastic processes
Suppose that i have a random variable $I(t) = \int_0^{t} N(s) e^{\sigma W(s)} ds$ where $N(s)$ is the number of arrivals at the time s ( notice that is not the total arrivals until time s, just the arrivals at s, so it follows a $ N(s) \sim Poisson(\lambda) $ at every time s) and $W(s)$ is a wiener process. $W(s)$ and $N(s)$ are independent
There's any way to derive the analytical distribution of $I(t)$?
I see that obtaining the expectation and variance are feasible since the two processes are independent, i wonder if its possible to derive all higher moments and recover the original distribution or even if there is any other way of obtaining the original distribution.

Welcome do CV. Maybe the independence between ${N(s)}_s$ and ${W(s)}_s$ could be claimed earlier?

Sorry, thanks for the warning !
